# cloud9 + mongodb + nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I using cloud9 ide coding new project. When I deploy on cloudfoundry from cloud9ide. I have error

> Application failed to start. Please note that CloudFoundry uses a different port to listen to. When calling 'listen()' use it like '.listen(process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT)'.

This is my source

> var port = (process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 3000);
>
> var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
>
> var http = require('http');
>
> var env = process.env.VCAP_SERVICES ? JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) : null;
>
> var mongodata = env['mongodb-1.8'][0]['credentials'];
>
> http.createServer(function (req, res) {
>
> res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
>
> res.end('Hello World\n'  + env);
>   }).listen(port, host);

This source have error when I get mongo object

> var mongodata = env['mongodb-1.8'][0]['credentials'];

But not have this line deploy successful

Please help me !!

Thanks so much

Comment: This seems to imply that `VCAP_SERVICES` is not available. Try removing that line. What do you see in the output when you visit the web server? You have `res.end('Hello World\n' + env);`, so you should be able to see whether or not those things are really defined in `env` or not. This looks like it's your doing, so you should know.

Comment: Shouldn't first line be `var port = (process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT)` according to the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error in the cloud9 console probably tells you (as it tells me when i try this :-) ):

```
haalasdoallalsakdl (CloudFoundry): [5/6] Crash log
============/logs/stderr.log============
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/haalasdoallalsakdl-0-8be0d413a9ec29a79f665d388ce414bd/app/server.js:7:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
```

So there is no entry in `VCAP_SERVICES` called like that. When I `console.log` the `process.env` variable, there isn't even any service listed.

So you'll have to install the mongodb service for your app. Fastest to do this is via the CF VMC tools (can't run this in cloud9 at the moment, so you'll have to install this locally):

```
vmc create-service mongodb --bind your_app_name
```

Then it'll start up fine.

*N.B. You can probably fix this in the .yml file, but I don't know how to do this :-)*

Comment: >>vmc create-service mongodb --bind your_app_name
when I deploy form local not have error, but when deploy by c9 have same error

Comment: I just tried this, and when i put the app i'm trying to deploy to from Cloud9 in place of `your_app_name` it works fine.